# $scope and VM are undefined In console - Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angualr 1.1.x - Inside all my controllers I am doing am using the key word this that I use to store all my data and access it in the html file.

```
var vm = this;
```

Then inside my HTML views I am delearing my controllers like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerName as vm">
```

But I have been wondering why when I call

$scope or vm in the console it turns out to be undifined.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Because the console will only list globals.

Comment: Note there are dev tools extensions like batarang that let you see scope also

Comment: Just use [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-inspector/gjhmfjbfdbeeekiijofbikifokdkfhcc?hl=en).

Comment: And by the way, you should upgrade your stack. AngularJS 1.1 is very old and has even been superseded by Angular which currently is at version 4.4.4.

Comment: 1. I'm working on a legacy app, so 1.1 is not optional